# Does Spatial Audio offer any advantage without Head Tracked Stereo?

Tags: apple-music

I suppose neither traditional headphones nor AirPods in Fixed Stereo benefit from spatial audio objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope.**

You need:

- AirPods Pro,
- AirPods Max
- AirPods (3rd generation)
- Beats Fit Pro

The built-in speakers and iOS or iPadOS 15.1 or later on

- iPhone 7 or later
- iPad Pro 12.9‑inch (3rd generation) and later
- iPad Pro 11‑inch
- iPad Air (3rd generation) and later
- iPad (6th generation) and later
- iPad mini (5th generation) and later

The built-in speakers on a Mac computer with Apple silicon

Apple TV 4K with tvOS 15

Audiovisual content from a supported app.

Info extracted from [this link at Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT211775)